# Non-CIFRE Industry PhD in France

Tags: phd, industry, france

I am exploring options in different European countries for doing an Industry PhD related to my work in industry. France's CIFRE program sounds like a good fit for my objectives, but I am unfortunately ineligible for it: as I have worked with my current employer (who would be my industry sponsor) for more than nine months, a CIFRE application would be rejected. I am wondering: in France, is CIFRE the only method for doing an industry PhD, or is there another program I could explore? Thank you for any insight!

Edit: To clarify, a [CIFRE](https://www.anrt.asso.fr/sites/default/files/cifre_plaquette_2019_eng.pdf) thesis is a specific mechanism which subsidizes a doctoral thesis being done by a researcher at an company jointly with a research laboratory. I am looking for options for a similar arrangement, but without this specific form of contract (as the ANRT [the government body responsible for approving these contracts] requires the company employee to have been employed for less than nine months at the time that the dossier is submitted to them for approval).